# Play video from base64 in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app which can encode and decode video from base64 and vice versa. At some point, I want to play this video from a base64 string without saving it to a file. I found the Uri method for videoview, but as I am not saving it to a file, I can't use the uri. I have a few guesses on what to use, maybe an output or input stream ?, I have managed to achieve the same in case of images (jpg/jpeg) using bitmap. But can I use the same for video? Or is there something similar to bitmap , but for videos ?

Thanks for any help at all